# requirements.txt - How to mark alternative packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am writing a project that relies on `tensorflow`, but that can be provided by either of two `pip` packages: `tensorflow` or `tensorflow-gpu`. My project works fine with either, but I don't want people running it on a machine without gpu support to have to install the extra overhead, but I still want people running on machines with gpu support to be able to leverage that. Is there a way to mark in my `requirements.txt` file that I require *either* `tensorflow` *or* `tensorflow-gpu` but not both?

**EDIT:**

In this specific case I should note that from the *programmer's* point of view, both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` are identical, as they both provide a module `tensorflow` which has the same functions/classes/methods etc., and only differ in that `tensorflow-gpu` benefits from GPU acceleration. The problem that I am having is that if I put `tensorflow` in `requirements.txt` then in order to run with GPU acceleration, users would have to do `pip install -r requirements.txt && pip uninstall tensorflow && pip install tensorflow-gpu` which is not ideal, and if I instead put `tensorflow-gpu` in `requirements.txt`, then it will require a bunch of unnecessary system libraries (CUDNN etc) and wont work out-of-the-box for non-gpu users.

**EDIT AGAIN**

As a work-around, I've decided to provide two different requirement files, `requirements.txt` and `requirements-gpu.txt`, both of which include a shared `-r .requirements-core.txt` and add their respective version of tensorflow. That way people who want GPU support can `pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt` but the standard `pip install -r requirements.txt` will still work out-of-the box for everyone.

Comment: No way. `pip` is rather a simplistic package manager and `requirements.txt` is just a straightforward list of dependencies. Conditions in `requirements.txt` can be set for Python version or architecture but that's all. No alterations at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot condition download packages with `requirements.txt`, but you might do one of the following solutions:

1 - Install both packages tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu as dependencies and do a try / except to choose which package will actually be used, like:

```
tensorflow = null

try:
  tensorflow = __import__("tensorflow-gpu")
  tensorflow.operation_that_requires_gpu()
except:
  tensorflow = __import__("tensorflow")
enter code here
```

2 - On your project you ask the client to pass the dependency direct to you:

```
def my_function_that_uses_tensorflow(tensorflow):
  # do stuff

from my_module import my_function_that_uses_tensorflow
import tensorflow # or tensorflow = __import__("tensorflow-gpu")
my_function_that_uses_tensorflow(tensorflow)
```

3 - If tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow both install their package with the same `tensorflow` name on your site-packages, then my suggestion is do a try /except as I said on option number 1, but don't include tensorflow-gpu or tensorflow as a dependency of your package (treat it as a "peer dependency" that the code using your package should include as their dependency in order to use it):

```
try:
  import tensorflow
except:
  raise ImportError('You need to include tensorflow or tensorflow-gpu as a dependency in order to use this package')
```

Comment: In this specific case, these steps are not useful because both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` act the same from the programmer's perspective (i.e. they both provide a module `tensorflow` which has identical functions/classes/methods/etc). This is useful for the general case, however.

Comment: @phsyron My second suggestion than would work, ask for the user to include the correct tensorflow lib as a dependency (like a peer dependency of your lib) and pass it as an argument to you

Or just try to `import tensorflow` with the try / except on your lib and say the user have to include the correct tensorflow as his dependency if it is missing

Answer (score 0):

There have been a handful of proposals for such functionality, but this currently does not exist within pip environment variables:

> ... currently PEP 508 does not provide environment
> markers for GPU/CUDA availability, which leads to problems for
> projects that want to provide distributions for environments with and
> without GPU support.
>
> As far as I can tell, there's been multiple suggestions to bring this
> issue to distutils-sig, but no one has actually done it.
>
> Relevant issues:
>
> - (closed) "How should Python packages depending on TensorFlow structure
>   their requirements?"
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7166
> - (closed) "Adding gpu or cuda specification in PEP 508"
>   https://github.com/python/peps/issues/581
> - (closed) "More support for conditional installation"
>   https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1353
> - (no response) "Adding gpu or cuda markers in PEP 508"
>   https://github.com/pypa/interoperability-peps/issues/68

There **is** however a 3rd party library for **TensorFlow** specifically, but it has its own set of caveats:

> There is now a third-party project which attempts to amend this for
> tensorflow (https://github.com/akatrevorjay/tensorflow-auto-detect) but this approach is somewhat fragile (depends on version numbers being in sync), doesn't directly scale to all similar projects, and would require maintainers for a given project to maintain *three* separate projects, instead of just one.

- [Environment markers for GPU/CUDA availibility](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/distutils-sig@python.org/thread/LXLF4YSC4WUZOYRX65DW7CESIX7UUBK5/) (Mailman 3 python.org)